# Connecting to Web service with Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, savon

I am trying to connect to a Webservice from Ruby with Savon - it is a SOAP based Webservice.  It also requires an x509 cert which I have the keys for but I am trying to bypass this at the minute just to get it working with ssl_verify_mode set to none

```
  client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL_URL,
                        log: true, # set to true to switch on logging
                        log_level: :debug,
                        convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
                        pretty_print_xml: true,
                        ssl_verify_mode: :none)
```

I have been able to generate my WSDL classes in .NET and hit the Webservice from c# client app.

My C# for the call to GetInformation from client is below

```
                var analysisTypes = new AnalysisType[4];
                analysisTypes[0] = AnalysisType.A;
                analysisTypes[1] = AnalysisType.B;
                analysisTypes[2] = AnalysisType.C;
                analysisTypes[3] = AnalysisType.D;

                var coord1 = new Coordinate {
                                       Id = i.ToString(),
                                       X = -110.5322,
                                       Y = 35.2108, QualityIndex = 90 };

                string ticketId = serviceClient.GetInformationsForCoordinates(
                                                           coord1, analysisTypes);
```

I am new to Ruby however and having difficulty in getting the same generated below to pass to Savon - so far I have got the following:

```
  coordinate = { Id: '1', X: -110.5322, Y: 35.2108, QualityIndex: 90 }
  ticket_id = client.call(:get_informations_for_coordinates,
                          message: coordinate)

  print ticket_id
```

This fails - I can see the SOAP message it sends below:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
              xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"
              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Body>
    <tns:GetInformationsForCoordinates>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <X>-110.5322</X>
      <Y>35.2108</Y>
      <QualityIndex>90</QualityIndex>
    </tns:GetInformationsForCoordinates>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

If I look at soap UI and click on the GetInformationsForCoordinates I can see how I should build up the SOAP message - what is the best way for me to Build up this type of message in Ruby - should I pass it all as a message and change the coordinate variable to be message?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/"
               xmlns:mun="http://WebService I want to hit"
               xmlns:mun1="http://WebService I want to Hit">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GetInformationsForCoordinates>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:coordReq>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mun:Basemap>?</mun:Basemap>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mun:GenerateReport>?</mun:GenerateReport>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mun:MapsForReport>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <mun1:HMap>?</mun1:HMap>
            </mun:MapsForReport>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mun:PortName>?</mun:PortName>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mun:Coordinates>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <mun:Coordinate>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <mun:Id>?</mun:Id>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <mun:QualityIndex>?</mun:QualityIndex>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <mun:X>?</mun:X>
                  <!--Optional:-->
                  <mun:Y>?</mun:Y>
               </mun:Coordinate>
            </mun:Coordinates>
         </tem:coordReq>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:analysisTypes>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <mun:AnalysisType>?</mun:AnalysisType>
         </tem:analysisTypes>
      </tem:GetInformationsForCoordinates>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid complex structures in the SOAP message. That would mean I'd not use an array as parameter. I'm not even sure whether that's supported at all.

You also might want to prefix the elements in your message, eg.:

```
coordinate = { 'tns:Id' => '1',
               'tns:X' => -110.5322,
               'tns:Y' => 35.2108, 
               'tns:QualityIndex' => 90 }
```

or whichever namespace defines those elements.

To build up a list of paramters one has build a hash for the message. The complete call would look like this (it's not a correct piece of code but it should give you the right direction to follow):

```
require 'pp'
require 'savon'

client = Savon.client(wsdl: WSDL_URL,
                    log: true, # set to true to switch on logging
                    log_level: :debug,
                    convert_request_keys_to: :camelcase,
                    pretty_print_xml: true,
                    ssl_verify_mode: :none)
rc = client.call(:get_informations_for_coordinates,
                  message: {
                     coordinates => { 'tns:Id' => '1',
                                      'tns:X' => -110.5322,
                                      'tns:Y' => 35.2108, 
                                      'tns:QualityIndex' => 90 },
                     analysis_types => {
                                      'tns:type0' => 'A',
                                      'tns:type1' => 'B'
                                    }
                  }
                 )
pp rc.to_hash
```

Comment: HI Stefan - and so were my C# call took too Parameters - Co-ordinate and AnalysisTypes - in Ruby when I call client.call(:get_informations_for_coordinates, - how should I pass in both coordinate and AnalysisTypes?

Comment: @KOL Please recheck my answer. I changed to reflect your question in your comment.